# Adaptive card json for microsoft form choice reponse

Tags: json, microsoft-teams, power-automate, adaptive-cards, microsoft-forms

I am using power automate to post a card to Microsoft Teams whenever a Microsoft Forms response is submitted.
The Microsoft form includes a choice field ("Operating System") that has 3 options ("iOS", "Android", and "Both").
I am using Adaptive Card json to make the card look better when it is posted to MS Teams. Inside the Adaptive Card json I am using Dynamic content to include the responses from the MS Form that was submitted.

I am getting a failure whenever I try to include the choice field response (Operating System):
(I think this is because the choice responses for operating system are not a text type buy possibly array?)

[image]

Could anyone provide a solution to handle the Operating System choice response?

Here is the error I am getting:

Line 39 is the line "text": "Operating System",(the dynamic content one) and if I select Android as the response this is the error that appears. If I select iOS as the response, the error will say "I" instead of "A".

```
Microsoft.Azure.ProcessSimple.Data.Entities.Exceptions.ProcessSimpleDataException: The specified Teams flowbot adaptive card request is missing or invalid. The tracking Id is '{0}'. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: A. Path 'body[5].text', line 39, position 17.
```

EDIT:
Adding all JSON for adaptive card:

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.2",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Title",
      "size": "large",
      "weight": "bolder",
      "wrap": true
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "@{outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/id#']}",
      "wrap": true
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Description",
      "size": "large",
      "weight": "bolder",
      "wrap": true
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "@{outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/id#']}",
      "wrap": true
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Operating System",
      "size": "large",
      "weight": "bolder",
      "wrap": true
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "@{outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/id#']}",
      "wrap": true
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT: Adding MS Forms response json

```
{
"responder":"email@email.com",
"submitDate":"8/23/2023 2:55:52 PM",
"id1":"This is a title",
"id2":"This is a description",
"id3":"[\"iOS\"]",
"id4":"",
"id5":""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct the correct format for Input.ChoiceSet,Like below-

```
  {
        "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
        "isMultiSelect":true,
        "placeholder": "",
        "id": "groceries",
        "isRequired": true,
        "label": "Groceries",
        "spacing": "Medium",
        "choices": 
        @{variables('choicevariable')}
    }
```

[image]
Also refer the below thread-
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Turn-CSV-into-Adaptive-Card-Choices/m-p/1623743#M180829

Comment: But i'm not wanting to add an input field. I want to add a field that displays the choice that was given in the forms response.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your requirement and share the json, so that we can try it from our end.

Comment: See original post for all of the JSON

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the data coming out is an array but even more interesting is that it's a serialised string.  For that reason, your error is a bit bizarre.  If it's just a string, it should map through.

Either way, if you want to parse the values, you can do it a couple of ways.

Firstly, I placed your forms response JSON in a variable so I could use it to demonstrate my answer.  The name of my variable is `Forms Response`.

```
{
    "responder": "email@email.com",
    "submitDate": "8/23/2023 2:55:52 PM",
    "id1": "This is a title",
    "id2": "This is a description",
    "id3": "[\"iOS\"]",
    "id4": "",
    "id5": ""
}
```

***Note:** Because the value is a string, you need to convert it to an array first and to do that, you need to use the `json` expression.  You'll see that used in my answers.*

#### First Option

You can use the first expression if you always expect a single value in the answer.

```
first(json(variables('Forms Response')?['id3']))
```

[image: First Option]

#### Join Option

Alternatively, if you expect more than one answer, you can always use the `join` expression to string them all together.

To demonstrate this one. I changed ID3 to look like this ...

```
 "id3": "[\"iOS\", \"Android\"]"
```

This is the expression I used ...

```
join(json(variables('Forms Response')?['id3']), ', ')
```

... and this is the outcome.

[image: Using Join]